# How to detect and remove a column that contains only null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In my table **table1** there are 6 columns Locations,a,b,c,d,e.

```
Locations [a]   [b]   [c]  [d]   [e]

[1]       10.00 Null  Null 20.00 Null

[2]       Null  30.00 Null Null  Null
```

i need the result like

```
Locations [a]   [b]   [d]

[1]       10.00 Null  20.00

[2]       Null  30.00 Null
```

My question is how to detect and delete column that contains all null values using sql query.
Is it possible?

If yes then please help and give sample.

Comment: you're gonna need lots of data-definition code and custom server syntax to do that. It would help if you could say on what database platform will table1 be.

Comment: I wonder why you would want to do that...

Comment: Er, @SWeko, isn't SQL Server 2005 the DBMS?

Comment: And now I feel kinda stupid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to detect whether a given column has only the `NULL` value:

```
SELECT 1  -- no GROUP BY therefore use a literal
  FROM Locations
HAVING COUNT(a) = 0 
       AND COUNT(*) > 0;
```

The resultset will either consist of zero rows (column `a` has a non-`NULL` value) or one row (column `a` has only the `NULL` value). FWIW this code is Standard SQL-92.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fast (and ugly) stored proc that takes the name of the table and print (or drop if you want it to)  the fields that are full of nulls.

```
ALTER procedure mysp_DropEmptyColumns 
  @tableName nvarchar(max)
as begin
  declare @FieldName nvarchar(max)
  declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
  declare @CountDef nvarchar(max)
  declare @FieldCount int

  declare fieldNames cursor  local fast_forward for
    select c.name
      from syscolumns c 
        inner join sysobjects o on c.id=o.id
      where o.xtype='U'
        and o.Name=@tableName

  open fieldNames 
  fetch next from fieldNames into @FieldName
  while (@@fetch_status=0)
  begin
    set @SQL=N'select @Count=count(*) from "'+@TableName+'" where "'+@FieldName+'" is not null'
    SET @CountDef = N'@Count int output';
    exec sp_executeSQL @SQL, @CountDef, @Count = @FieldCount output
    if (@FieldCount=0)
    begin
      set @SQL = 'alter table '+@TableName+' drop column '+@FieldName
      /* exec sp_executeSQL @SQL */
      print @SQL
    end
    fetch next from fieldNames into @FieldName
  end

  close fieldNames
end
```

This uses a cursor, and is a bit slow and convoluted, but I suspect that this is a kind of procedure that you'll be running often

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone who stumbles across this, it would also be worth quoting the column and table names.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is more about working on *rows* rather than *columns*.

If you're talking about deleting rows where c is null, use:

```
delete from table1 where c is null
```

If you're talking about dropping a column when all rows have null for that column, I would just find a time where you could lock out the DB from users and execute one of:

```
select c from table1 group by c
select distinct c from table1
select count(c) from table1 where c is not null
```

Then, if you only get back just NULL (or 0 for that last one), weave your magic (the SQL Server command *may* be different):

```
alter table table1 drop column c
```

Do this for whatever columns you want.

You really need to be careful if you're deleting columns. Even though they may be full of nulls, there may be SQL queries out there that use that column. Dropping the column will break those queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c IS NOT NULL  -- or also SELECT COUNT(*)
```

To detect if indeed this column has no values at all.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN c
```

is the query to remove the column if it is deemed desirable.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this stored procedure with your table name as input.

```
alter proc USP_DropEmptyColumns 

@TableName varchar(255)
as
begin

Declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)

DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = @TableName

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * FROM [' + @TableName + '] WHERE [' + @col + '] IS NOT NULL) 

                        BEGIN 
                        ALTER TABLE [' + @TableName + ']  DROP Column [' + @col + ']
                        end'
    EXEC(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC PRINT DATA=TABLE1;RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=TABLE1 OUT=TRANS1;VAR A B C D E;RUN;

DATA TRANS2;SET TRANS1;IF COL1 = . AND COL2 = . THEN DELETE;RUN;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=TRANS2 OUT=TABLE2 (DROP=_NAME_);VAR COL1-COL2;RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=TABLE2;RUN;
```

Comment: I’d recommend including additional explanation of how this addresses the original question and why you feel it’s the best approach, instead of simply providing script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the stored proc on all the tables in your database.

```
DECLARE @table_name AS VARCHAR(128);

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.tables;

OPEN table_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC USP_DropEmptyColumns @table_name;
    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name;
END;

CLOSE table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE table_cursor;
```