# How to return Nothing, if Value is NULL in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-services

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT r.NAME AS REGIONNAME, s.NAME AS STADTNAME, f.ADRESSE AS STRASSEADRESSE 
FROM REGION r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN STADT s ON s.REGION_ID = r.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GEBAEUDE f ON s.ID = f.STADT_ID 
ORDER BY r.NAME
```

If I use this statement in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, it works like I wanted.
The output is:

[image: Picture]

On the client-side I am working with Xcode. My problem is that I return `REGIONNAME`, `STADTNAME` and `STRASSENADRESSE` in a TableView. If the `STRASSENADRESSE` value in the database is `NULL`, Xcode returns an empty row.

Is it possible, if the `STRASSENADRESSE` Value is `NULL`, that the web service only returns the `REGIONNAME` and `STADTNAME`? If yes how can I do that.

Thx in advance

Comment: i posted my query. Look at my Question

Comment: you want to return an empty string, or you don't want to return  STRASSENADRESSE  column ? I mean, do you only want to return two columns if STRASSENADRESSE value is null ? In that case, you have to return two tables, one with 3 columns and another one with 2 columns. Confirm if it's that what you want, and I'll post the querys

Comment: Yes i want return two columns if STRASSENADRESSE value is null and if STRASSENADRESSE has a value i want to return 3 columns. you are correct.

Comment: So use two querys. See my answer

Comment: @Bashud, do you just want to convert the `NULL` values to empty string or do you want to remove a whole column if all rows are `NULL` for that column?

Comment: @Bashud, This SO sounds exactly like what you are asking, but the answer looks weird. Worth a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665868/how-to-detect-and-remove-a-column-that-contains-only-null-values

Comment: No, if you have a SQL query, you're returning n rows of a given shape. If your SELECT statement selects three columns or expression, **all** your rows will have three columns. You cannot change that. You should find a way to convert your `NULL` to something meaningful like `(no name)` or something like that, using the `ISNULL(columnname, value-if-null)` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this query will return 3 columns

`SELECT 
r.NAME AS REGIONNAME, s.NAME AS STADTNAME, f.ADRESSE AS STRASSEADRESSE 
FROM REGION r 
LEFT OUTER JOIN STADT s  ON s.REGION_ID = r.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GEBAEUDE f ON s.ID = f.STADT_ID ORDER BY r.NAME
WHERE f.ADRESSE IS NOT NULL`

this one will return only two values, when the STRASSEADRESSE  value is `null`

`SELECT 
    r.NAME AS REGIONNAME, s.NAME AS STADTNAME, 
    FROM REGION r 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STADT s  ON s.REGION_ID = r.ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GEBAEUDE f ON s.ID = f.STADT_ID ORDER BY r.NAME
    WHERE f.ADRESSE IS NULL`

you will have to recieve them in two  distinct TableView, one with 3 columns and another one with 2 columns

Comment: thx you for that, but how can i use 2 querys in a SQLCommand?

Comment: you can do multiple querys in SQLCommand. You can see an example here. http://ryangaraygay.com/blog/post/Multiple-Select-Queries-in-one-SqlCommand.aspx
So readapt this example to your code :) If this works for you, don't forget tick my answer as correct ! (sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) SQL function to return an empty string, or some other default value.

```
SELECT 
 r.NAME AS REGIONNAME, 
 s.NAME AS STADTNAME, 
 ISNULL(f.ADRESSE,'') AS STRASSEADRESSE 
FROM 
 REGION r LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 STADT s ON s.REGION_ID = r.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 GEBAEUDE f ON s.ID = f.STADT_ID 
ORDER BY 
 r.NAME
```

Comment: But this will always return 3 columns. I think OP wants to return 2 or 3 columns conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if 'ADRESSE' is NULL Or not..

You can use **WHEN** ans **IS NULL** functions..

```
SELECT 
 r.NAME AS REGIONNAME, 
 s.NAME AS STADTNAME, 
 CASE f.ADDRESS
     WHEN f.ADRESSE IS NULL THEN '' 
     ELSE f.ADDRESS
 END AS STRASSEADRESSE 
FROM 
 REGION r LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 STADT s ON s.REGION_ID = r.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 GEBAEUDE f ON s.ID = f.STADT_ID 
ORDER BY 
 r.NAME
```

Check this links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx