# How to avoid a column from select query conditionally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select columns from a table conditionally,I Just followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290994/sql-conditional-column-data-return-in-a-select-statement),

```
SELECT ID,(CASE WHEN @check=0
          THEN Teacher END) 'Teacher'
FROM Register
```

Result when `@check =1`

```
---------------------
|   ID   | Teacher  |
---------------------
|   10   |  NULL    |
|   20   |  NULL    |
--------------------
```

In this case I don't want to select `Teacher` Column,How to do this?

If it is not possible How to delete column which has null value for all row ?

Comment: AS I know this is not possible with column select statement, however you can delete column after select statement

Comment: @SandipPatel How to delete column which has only null value for all rows

Comment: You cant delete the column, just create a dynamic query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect and remove a column that contains only null values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665868/how-to-detect-and-remove-a-column-that-contains-only-null-values)

Comment: is @check =0 means 0 index column?? i.e ID?? what if it is 2??

Answer (score 2):

Use a `IF ELSE` condition

```
IF @check = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, Teacher 'Teacher'
    FROM Register
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM Register
END
```

OR use a dynamic query like below

```
DECLARE @qryStr VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @check INT =0
SET @qryStr = 'SELECT ID '+CASE WHEN @check=0 THEN ',Teacher' ELSE '' END +' FROM Register'
PRINT @qryStr
EXEC(@qryStr)
```

Comment: :) This is possible but This is not I want. It is not possible in my case since there are multiple columns, to describe the question I chose simple example with one column

Comment: I have just modified the answer. Please check whether that will help

Comment: In my case I have multiple columns with different condition

Comment: Just share your requirement properly.

Answer (score 0):

This dynamical qry is not good idea. You should rewrite your solution or denormalize your tables.

**Variant 1:**

```
declare @removeCol1 bit = 1
declare @removeCol3 bit = 1

declare @qry varchar(4000) = 'select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from dbo.yourtable'

if @removeCol1 = 1 set @qry = replace(replace(@qry, 'col1,', ''), 'col1', '')
if @removeCol3 = 1 set @qry = replace(replace(@qry, 'col3,', ''), 'col3', '')

print @qry
exec (@qry)
```

**Variant 2:**
Use pivot on your table and filter properly. But your example isn't enought for example query.